# Loading data into tableview on click of row in other tablet not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two table views within my view controller, they are both controlled by the same controller.
When the user clicks a cell in the first data should be taken from a database and populate the second. I have everything working apart from actually getting the data to load into the table on the click.
The table the user will click on is `_lst_CourseList` and the table to display the data is `_tbl_notes`

```
NSMutableArray *Notes;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    Notes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ...
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == _lst_CourseList){
        return [courseSections count];
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == _lst_CourseList){
        if (alphabetic){
            return courseSections;
        }
        return nil;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == _lst_CourseList){
        return [courseSections objectAtIndex:section];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == _lst_CourseList){
        NSString *sectionTitle = [courseSections objectAtIndex:section];
        NSArray *sectionCourses = [courseDict objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        return [sectionCourses count];
    } else {
        [Notes count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == _lst_CourseList){
        ...
    } else {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"notecell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        // Configure the cell...
        KCNote *note = [Notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *Author =(UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *Date = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
        UILabel *Note = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:3];

        Author.text = note.Author;
        Date.text = note.Date;
        Note.text = note.Note;

        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.933 green:0.251 blue:0.208 alpha:1];
        bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
        return cell;
    }

}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == _lst_CourseList){
        ...
        [self getNotes:course.id];
        ...
    }
}

-(void)getNotes:(NSInteger)courseid{
    [Notes removeAllObjects];
    FMResultSet *s;
    s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM notes WHERE CourseID =?;", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", courseid]];
    //s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM notes;"];
    if ([db hadError]) {
        NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
    }
    while ([s next]) {
        NSInteger NoteID = [s intForColumnIndex:0];
        NSString *Note = [s stringForColumnIndex:2];
        NSString *Author = [s stringForColumnIndex:3];
        NSString *date = [s stringForColumnIndex:4];
        KCNote *note = [KCNote new];
        note.NoteID = NoteID;
        note.Note = note;
        note.Author = Author;
        note.Date = date;
        [Notes addObject:note];
    }
    [_tbl_notes reloadData];
}
```

I can see that the Notes have been found in the database and at the end of `getNotes` The array has all the note objects that need to be displayed but it seems the `reloadData` does not reload and display this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put **return** infront of **[NOTES count];** See below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == _lst_CourseList){
        NSString *sectionTitle = [courseSections objectAtIndex:section];
        NSArray *sectionCourses = [courseDict objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        return [sectionCourses count];
} else {
    return [Notes count];
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you set the delegate and dataSource of both tables to self?

Comment: Yes both have the deletegate and dataSouce as the view controller

Comment: Well, I think the only problem may be in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Do you use custom cells there? Try to put an NSLog there to see how many times it gets called.

Comment: The block in the if tableView == _lst_CourseList gets called as i should however the else is never called

Comment: How did you add the tables to your view, programmatically or using IBOutlets?

Comment: How did you layout the tables? I need to see that.